# How do I clear the command history in the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Is there a command to clear the history from within the mongo shell?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There should be a file called .dbshell in your home folder. Just delete it.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB terminal history is stored inside the `~/.dbshell`file. Just empty the `.dbshell` file

```
 $ > ~/.dbshell
```

> Versions of Windows mongo.exe earlier than 2.2.0 will save the .dbshell file in the mongo.exe working directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can clear  contents on the shell by Ctrl + L

Comment: As the question was about clearing the history (which also means the previously used commands) on the window and the Ctrl + L option was introduced recently in the latest version of the shell, i thought this would help others to know about it.

Comment: @praveena_kd...I found it useful. Exactly what I wanted. +1.

Comment: Ctrl+L wipes the actual command history now? Not just scrolling the window to hide output history? that's very good to know if so! It doesn't in my shell (Ctrl+R as well as [UP] both retrieve commands) but good to keep in mind.

Comment: None of the comments thusfar explain why this answer is unhelpful.  Ctrl+L clears what you "see" in your shell (scrolls you to the current line and erases scroll history), but leaves the actual history of those commands in tact (you can still up arrow to see them, or Ctrl+r to search them).  Only deleting the file on disk removes the history of them.

This answer is helpful however if you came to this article trying to answer the question "how do I clear my mongo shell's output" rather than "how do I clear  my mongo shell's history".  A little disclaimer in the answer would clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```bash
sudo rm ~/.mongodb/mongosh/mongosh_repl_history
```

Once that's done, all of your history will have been deleted from the MongoDB Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Command history is stored in **[~/.dbshell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-dbshell-file)** file.

For example, on a Unix-like system:

```
# Ensure an empty history file
echo "" > ~/.dbshell

# Remove rwx access to the history file
chmod 0 ~/.dbshell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MongoDB Shell as a standalone package, you will find the shell history file located in `~/.dbshell`

If you're using the embedded MongoDB Shell inside **MongoDB Compass**, you will find the shell history file located in `~/.config/MongoDB Compass/MongoDB Compass/shell-history.json`

Just empty the history file